# Getting values querying from same table with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table like this:

```
+----+--------+----------+---------+-------------+
| ID | Codigo |  Nombre  | PadreID | CatalogosID |
+----+--------+----------+---------+-------------+
|  2 | KNW    | KENWORTH |       0 | MAR         |
|  3 | VLV    | VOLVO    |       0 | MAR         |
|  4 | T60    | T600     |       2 | MOD         |
|  5 | T68    | T680     |       2 | MOD         |
|  6 | T88    | T880     |       2 | MOD         |
|  7 | M43    | VNM 430  |       3 | MOD         |
+----+--------+----------+---------+-------------+
```

First I want to get a list of parameter I received so in LINQ I do something like:

```
var cr = _pService.Listar().Where(x => x.CatalogosID == Catalogo)
```

Supposing `Catalogo = MOD` so it get values with ID is 4,5,6,7

Once I get them I want to get values where `PadreID = ID` so I should receive as finall result only values with `ID 2 and 3`

How can I do this Query with LINQ? Can someone help me there? I think it´s a self join, but joins with LINQ are very confusing

Comment: You mean a filter with two columns? Just use two conditions with and, something like .Where(x => x.CatalogosID == Catalogo && x.PadreId == ID)

Comment: what are the column names produces by `_pService.Listar()`?

Comment: No, I don´t want to filter by two columns, if I do as you say, I dont have any results because ID 2,3 are not CatalogosID = MOD @Esko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you want to get rows with ID = 2 and ID = 3 if their `CatalogosID` isn't "MOD". Also, there aren't any rows where PadreID = ID. Please review your post and question.

**EDIT** 
`var idsWithMod = _p.service.Where(p => p.CatalogosID = Catalogo).Select(p => p.PadreID).ToList();` 
`var result = _pservice.Where(p => idsWithMod.IndexOf(p.ID) != -1).ToList();` 
I wrote it in two queries to be more clear. If you want, you can combine them.

Comment: Yes you´re right, `CatalogosID` is "MOD" only in ID 4,5,6 and 7 but I have column called   `PadreID`, so I want a subquery or something like that to compare that PadreID with ID and finally get rows with ID = 2 and ID = 3 , you got it?

Comment: But PadreID is never equal to ID. Explain it better, please. Maybe step by step.

Comment: PadreID of ID 4,5,6 and 7 equals are 2 and 3.... these PadreID I want to use to compare with ID

Comment: I understood now. I will write the query in a minute and post it.

Comment: WOW, it works but can you explain me what it do?, I dont understand part of  `IndexOf(p.ID) != -1` why use indexOf and why != -1?

Comment: idsWithMod is a list of integers. It contains all those 2, 2, 2 and 3. IndexOf is a method of the data type List. When the list doesn't contain an integer it returns -1 so the part `Where(p => idsWithMod.IndexOf(p.ID) != -1)` selects those rows where their id is in the list. Hope you understood. If not, check IndexOf in the msdn library.

Comment: If you can upvote my question I really appreciated it. I need 15 reputation to upvote your answer. Regards